# Подойдет ли переходник, SSD для материнской платы

Tags: железо

[переходник PCI-E M.2 NGFF for SSD Bulk](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/parts/controllers/1083421/) и 
[SSD SAMSUNG 970 EVO Plus MZ-V7S250BW 250Гб](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/hdd/ssd_in/1128416/).
Будут ли работать в связке с материнской платой Gigabyte GA-Z68P-DS3 rev.1 ???

Comment: Это форум программистов, а не компьютерщиков. Если нужно спросить по поводу железа, вам подойдёт [Киберфорум](https://www.cyberforum.ru/hardware/)

Comment: Подойдет по идее, разъем типа M на обоих, но покупка сомнительная.

Comment: Просто я увидел тут метку Железо и подумал, что можно задать такой вопрос.

Comment: @АлексейШиманович, ну вроде тут тоже про железо можно спрашивать.

Comment: Вроде как именно по программированию железа, ведь на этом форуме так же сидят низкоуровневые программисты